# How to Notify Beta Users that App is Live on Google Playstore ?

Tags: android

I uploaded an App on Google Play Store for Beta Testing and added some users as Beta users. Now when App is going live on play store ,Then how Beta users will get notified about the app as there are some changes after Beta launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Google Play](https://play.google.com/) will send a notification to all your Beta testers if:

---

#1. `versionCode` of the APK on the market is higher than the `versionCode` of the previously installed version

#2. `PackageName` still the same

#3. Same certificate has been used to sign your application

---

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9131671/1549700)