# Does Google Play Store send "Beta App Update" notification to "Beta Testers"?

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, apk, beta-testing

My question is little more specific to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131625/does-google-play-send-update-notification-to-beta-testers)

My App is not yet published into production. We have published few beta versions of the app on Play Store.

My question is **Does Google Play Store send "Beta App Update" notification to "Beta Testers"?**

e.g. My App previous Beta version code is 4 which is already available with few Beta Testers and I updated App version code to 5 in Beta itself, now will my Beta Testers receive an App Update notification from Google Play Store?

This was my 5th Beta App Update but not a single Beta Tester have received an App Update Notification for each app update we did so far.

> **How does it relate with the OPEN Beta Testing and CLOSED Beta Testing?**
>
> **Is it that Google Play Store only sends app update notification to Production App Updates?**

Any suggestions and reference links to the official docs will be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching for a while, we got know that we were

1. using 2 Gmail ids on one device and
2. non tester **(not yet "become a tester")** Gmail ids in other device.

When we removed one email id from play store and asked to do "become a tester", we had to wait for notification to receive but we didn't receive it yet again.

On Next Day, My colleague helped me to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751917/1576416):

> **Nothing with Google Play is automatic. They have a caching system much like Apple App Store among others. According to this caching system, once or twice a day the cache system gets flushed and the market (Play Store) gets updated about this data. At some point after that, the updates get pushed. This can be a multi-day process unfortunately. If you've not missed any setting then, i guess, all you can do is wait a while (at least next 24 Hrs after the update is live).**

And Yes!!!! We received a **Beta App Update** notification from Play Store after a wait time of nearly 24 Hrs. The time can be less in some cases but I don't know why it took so much time for us.

I hope this might help someone looking for similar answers.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Google Play sends notification to the Beta testers if an old version of app is install in device